# Why AMP with structured data requires at least 1200 pixels wide image?

Tags: image, resolution, mobile-website, amp-html, structured-data

AMP pages that have structured data need at least 1200 pixels wide marked-up image. But the NON-AMP version only need 696 pixels wide image.

Any reason why the mobile search result needs such a large image?

Doc: [Link to AMP DOC](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#amp-sd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to make a guess I would say it is to ensure the images are crisp when viewed on a high DPI screen. 696px might look fine on something that has a fairly low DPI, but on a higher quality screen with a high DPI 696px may be fuzzy and probably show some JPG artifacts. Where as a 1200px image scaled down will remain crisp on all displays.